# Capture Approval Comments

Tags: approval-process, approval-step, approval-history, approve-action

Is there any way to capture approval comments in an approval process and store them to a text field using any of the automations?
I have seen a way to do it using a trigger and call an approval process for requesting and approving, but how to capture the comments and store them?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query on ProcessInstance first

```
select Id, TargetObjectId from ProcessInstance where TargetObjectId in :SobjectIDS
```

than, from those processInstance you need to query ProcessInstanceStep to get Comments

```
Select Comments,ProcessInstanceId from ProcessInstanceStep where ProcessInstanceId in :ProcessInstaceIds
```

You can refere [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000I3uzQAC) link for similar ask

Comment: Thanks @Abhinav Thakur..Currently I am using a trigger which is as follows:How can I use this condition here?

Comment: If( c.Stage__c =='Program Approved') {                    
                    Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1= new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
                    req1.setComments('Request for approving from the finance team ');
                    req1.setObjectId(c.id);
                    req1.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId('Approval_Process');
                    //req.setNextApproverIds(new Id[]{c.Request_Approval_From__c});
                    Approval.ProcessResult res1 = Approval.process(req1); 
                }